# Invoice and receipt statements API for 'My account'

Tags: paypal, payment, billing, invoice, stripe-payments

I want to add Payment History to a user's account.
On this page, a user should see payments received (via PayPal) and payments made (via Stripe or PayPal). I want them to be able to download the receipts in PDF form as shown here in a mockup: [Mock Image of Payment History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsyc4.png)

The details on the PDF should simply include: Date, Reference Number, Amount Paid or Amount Received.

What would be the best way to generate these statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PayPal there is a transaction search API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1

If the user creates a new live Rest API APP and checks the box for the permission needed and copy-pastes the clientid/secret into the config of your system, you'd be able to run this call on their behalf and assemble some history with repeat API calls.

It'd be simpler for them to log into their account and generate an activity download as a CSV file, though.